# What is the difference between Powerpoint Theme and Powerpoint template?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I am working on PowerPoint macro. In that I want to apply theme programatically but in that i just want to ask user like which layout you want to apply for that slide.
But when i say `theme.apply` it just apply automatically layouts to the slide.

So i just confuse whats the difference between Powerpoint Theme and Powerpoint template?
so that i will try to use template instead of theme, if it do the same work what theme does like change the chart color by default theme color like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to guys at microsoft A Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007 template is a pattern or blueprint of a slide or group of slides that you save as a .potx file.

To give your presentations a designer-quality look — a look that includes one or more slide layouts with coordinating colors, a matching background, fonts, and effects, you'll want to apply a theme.

try this
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/understand-the-difference-between-powerpoint-templates-and-themes-HA010357528.aspx